# Cypress - wait until some element which is "reattached" with different content

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I want to wait until our application import some data, which may literally takes from 1 second to 2 minutes.

I want to wait until "Example B" number has value greater than 0 (number is always greater than 100, so I can use e.g. `cy.contains('td', /^[1-9][0-9]{2,3}$/)`).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Example A</td>
        <td>0</td> <!-- number -->
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Example B</td>
        <td>0</td> <!-- number -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is, that the `<td>` element is removed and replaced by new.

But, there can be some "in-between steps", because during importing data there can be some other external actions and  can be removed/added multiple times.

For example:

1. default state: `<td>0</td>` is presented
2. in-between step: `<td>0</td>` is replaced by `<td>0</td>`
3. in-between step: `<td>0</td>` is replaced by `<td>0</td>`
4. expected state: `<td>0</td>` is replaced by `<td>1245</td>`

These " in-between steps" may or may not occur.

This code:

```
cy.contains('tr', 'Example B').children().eq(2).should('match', /^[1-9][0-9]+$/);
```

gives this error, which is right, because `<td>` is realy detached.

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.should() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.
```

We are using Angular, SignalR, Redux, ...